# how can i set xcode configuration with pod package --configuration?

Tags: ios

Because my code include category, I have to set `-ObjC` and `-all_load` for configuration arguments to generate static framework, right?

But, what a problem is, I had tried to search so many reference but how to use configuration but debug and configuration arguments not mentioned.
I have tried as many ways which I could think of e.g. in podspec file I had tried set s.xcconfig => 
`{"OTHER_LDFLAGS" => "$(inherited) -Objc"}`, but they can not work.

Comment: Please don't put your personal email address in your question

Comment: Formatted you post